# Streamreader: How do I break out of an outside loop from an if block when reading

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am updating a line in a daily-generated file, but I know the line I'm looking for will be in the first 20 lines of at least 30,000 more. Is there a way to cancel the stream reading when the line replace is completed? What I'm looking for is to update the errant line and overwrite the existing file. (The program that generates it does not have the ability to fix it before creating the file.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strSourcePath);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
         string line = sr.ReadLine();
         if (line.Contains("hello world")) 
         {
             line.Replace("hello world","Hello World!");
         }//if
    }//while
```

Comment: use `break;`? This has nothing to do with `StreamReader`.

Comment: What you expect this code to do? You can't insert more data magically into middle of a file, `String.Replace` does not change string it is called on, `StreamReader` likely buffers content so you'll not know where it stopped...

Comment: Perhaps setting the value of the StreamReader to EndOfStream would be enough to exit the looping.

Answer (score 3):

Use `break;` to break out of loops.

Comment: If you use break in the if block, does that break you out of the While loop also?

Comment: Best thing to do is test it yourself, but "yes" it will break you out of a while loop: while (true)
            {
                break;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexi's comment, I realized that I need to go through the whole file anyway, if I'm processing it through StreamWriter. Break gets me out of the block, but ended up not being the ideal way to run the program.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strSourcePath);
StreamWriter swUpdatedFile = new StreamWriter(strSourcePath.Replace(".txt", ".dat"), false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
      string line = sr.ReadLine();
      if (line.Contains("hello world"))
      {
           swUpdatedFile.WriteLine("Hello World!");

      }//if
      else 
      { 
           swUpdatedFile.WriteLine(line);
      }

  }//while
```